# Couldn't connected to Magento 1 database: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: magento2, migration

Error : Couldn't connected to Magento 1 database: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
[image][image]

Comment: Check if your mysql services are running or not, Restart your xamp and after that open phpmyadmin and if it's working fine then try and if still getting error then check with your host and port.

Comment: I have installed services now but error is as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first your localhost of magento 1 projects.

If its working or not, if your local server is not working at that time above error are thrown.

```
Restart your wamp/xampp server try first with magento 1 project url if its working then try with migration of your projects from magento 1 to magento 2.
```

First run your magento 1 so you can go further for migration settings otherwise first resolve your local issue.

Comment: magento 1 working fine...

Comment: have you check your magento 2 dbname and host are correct, also check your magento 2 server is working or not?

Comment: but still error remains...

Comment: Yes that working fine..

Comment: but still error remains... as it is